# Adding a cors package makes my express server not load

Tags: node.js, express, cors

So I've set up a simple express.js app:

```js
import express, { Express, Request, Response } from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';



dotenv.config();

const PORT: string | number = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const app: Express = express();


app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send('Simple server');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Running on ${PORT} ⚡`));
```

which seems to be working as expected:[image]

But after I try to add a cors package (to manage cors in future):

```
import express, { Express, Request, Response } from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cors from 'cors';


dotenv.config();

const PORT: string | number = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const app: Express = express();

app.use(cors);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send('Simple server');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Running on ${PORT} ⚡`));
```

my server seems to be somehow "stuck" and is not loading at all:
[image]

What's up with that? How do I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [want](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#usage)

```js
app.use(cors());
```

and you have

```js
app.use(cors);   /* wrong */
```